# Scala foldLeft with a List

Tags: scala, functional-programming, foldleft

I have the following code snippet:

```
import scala.io.Source
object test extends App {

  val lineIterator = Source.fromFile("test1.txt").getLines()


  val fileContent = lineIterator.foldLeft(List[String]())((list, currentLine) => { 
    currentLine :: list
    list
    })


    fileContent foreach println

}
```

Let's assume the `test1.txt` file is not empty and has some values in it.
So my question about the `foldLeft` function is, why does this example here return an empty list, and when I remove the `list` at the end of the `foldLeft` function it works?
Why is it returning an empty list under the value `fileContent`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line `currentLine :: list` does not mutate the original list. It creates a new list with `currentLine` prepended, and returns that new list. When this expression is not the last one in your block, it will just be discarded, and the (still) empty `list` will be returned.

When you remove the `list` at the end, you will actually return `currentLine :: list`.

Comment: nice explanation...thats what I thought also

Answer (score 2):

You call `foldLeft` with some start value (in your case an empty list) and a function, which takes an accumulator and the current value. This function returns the new list then. In your implementation the empty list from the first call will propagate to the end of function execution. This is why you get an empty list as a result.

Please look at this example: https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/collections.html#fold

Answer (score 0):

list is immutable, so it is still empty after currentLine :: list. Thus the code within brackets returns an empty List, which is then folded with the next item, still returning an empty List.